# How to obfuscating multiple javascript files into one, and still run electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Problem:

How do I obfuscate multiple javascript files into one javascript file, where I still can run it with Nodejs Electron?

Thoughts:

I know that you can obfuscate all javascript files in an Electron project and still run it, but is it possible to obfuscate all into one main.js?

Answer (score 0):

Running your JS in Electron or in a browser is irrelevant to the concatenation and/or obfuscation. Same with Node.

You can always concatenate your JS project files(i.e. gather all your files in a single JS file). You have plenty build engines for this task, the most popular today being webpack.

As for obfuscation, usually it is already good enough with minification when you allow mangling internal variables (which is the default setting of most minifiers). The most popular today being Uglify, and you can easily combine it with build engines.